# Laravel 5.4 Dingo Route Binding

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware, dingo-api

I'm attempting to bind a function to the routing so it takes effect globally.
Basically I'm using Hashids to obfuscate the IDs, and want to be able to decode the ID on the route level so I don't need to do it everywhere the ID is uses in different controllers.

I've attempted to do the following at the top of the api routes file:

**api.php**

```
<?php

    use Dingo\Api\Routing\Router;
    use Hashids\Hashids;

    Route::bind('id', function ($id) {
        return Hasher::decode($id);
    });

    /** @var Router $api */
    $api = app(Router::class);
```

But it doesn't seem to have any effect.

I have a couple of routes that use the ID I want to decode at the bottom of the routes file:

```
$api->get('leads/{id}', 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\LeadController@show');
$api->put('leads/update/{id}', 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\LeadController@update');
```

Really at a loss as to how to get this to work, I've tried using $api->bind and others but they all call undefined functions.

Sure this is an easy thing, but I'm just starting out with Laravel so this is a bit beyond me at this point.

Many thanks!

---

Based on the hint that Serge gave me, I've attempted to move this functionality into Middleware, but still due to a full lack of understanding, this isn't working.

I have the following middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Junity\Hashids\Facades\Hashids;

class DecodeHashids
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if($request->has('id'))
            $request->id = Hasher::decode($request->id);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I've added it to Kernal.php:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
            'decode',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,

        'jwt.auth' => GetUserFromToken::class,
        'jwt.refresh' => RefreshToken::class,

        'decode' => \App\Http\Middleware\DecodeHashids::class,
    ];
}
```

and added it in the api routes file as so:

```
$api->group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function(Router $api) {
        $api->get('protected', function() {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Access to protected resources granted! You are seeing this text as you provided the token correctly.'
            ]);
        });

        $api->get('refresh', [
            'middleware' => 'jwt.refresh',
            function() {
                return response()->json([
                    'message' => 'By accessing this endpoint, you can refresh your access token at each request. Check out this response headers!'
                ]);
            }
        ]);

        $api->group(['middleware' => 'decode'], function(Router $api) {
            $api->get('leads/{id}', 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\LeadController@show');
        });
```

I get no errors, but the ID is not decoded when it passes through to the controller.

Comment: Are you familiar with Middleware? Many ways to skin this cat... you could scan all requests and transform them on the fly in the middleware or attach the specific middleware to the routes that need it...

Comment: @Serge Looked at Laravel documentation on middleware and have set something up, but no decoding is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help from Serge, I managed to complete the Middleware.

Middleware as below, it updates the *Route ID Parameter* with the decoded value, and this Middleware is added to the Kernal.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Hashids;

class DecodeHashids
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if($request->route()->parameters('id'))
            $request->route()->setParameter('id', Hashids::decode($request->id));

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then in the API route file, I added a new group that uses the 'decode' Middleware:

```
$api->group(['middleware' => 'decode'], function(Router $api) {
    $api->get('leads/{id}', 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\LeadController@show');
});
```

Can then of course add as many routes to this group where parameters need decoded.

Thanks Serge and the Laravel community for the help and responses on here and other sites. Hopefully this will help others.